# How to disable all keys in key board except tab key

Tags: javascript, html

How to disable all keys in key board except tab key for select box in html. Can any one provide the code for this one?
Below is i tried below code but it was not working

Comment: You're missing code.

Comment: .. there is no code. also, please explain why you want to do this. it sounds like you maybe just want a non-editable field.

Comment: Provide us with what you have tried so far and we will give you a hand.

Comment: <select onkeydown="keydownhandler()">
    <option>XXX</option>
    <option>YYY</option>
</select>

Comment: <select onkeydown="keydownhandler()">
    <option value="foo">Foo</option>
    <option value="bar">Bar</option>
</select>
function keydownhandler()

Comment: function keydownhandler(){if(event.keyCode!=8){event.returnValue=false;}}

Comment: And i tried with event.preventDefault also but this too not working

Comment: I need it in my project, No it must be editable but when the select box is in focus all key board events must be disabled along with arrows also except tab key @hoijui

Comment: don't put code into comments in an unreadable fashion, but rather edit your answer, so it contains all the stuff one needs to know. one should not be required to read the comments to understand the question. also properly format the code (indenting it with 4 spaces or with a TAB).

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you..put textbox and selectbox in the page..

```
document.getElementById("li1").onkeydown = function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
```

}

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kfs6budc/)

Comment: Hi, this one not working, up,down arrows are working and keys too

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to do exactly, but if you use jQuery this is fairly simple:

```
$('html, body').keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode !== 9) { // 9 = tab
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

If you want to disable keys only when a given element has focus, you can change the selector inside $().

Comment: I don,t want for entire page, i need only for a select box, thank you

Comment: Please check this: https://jsfiddle.net/46d5h523/1/ I put 2 select where only tab key is working, and a textarea where all keys are enabled.

Comment: This one also not working, is there any browser compatibility for this?

Comment: I have it working in all major browsers (latest version of chrome/IE/firefox). What browser/version do you use?

Comment: Am using chrome 43, It's not working. When i click up and down arrows and keys are also firing the event

Comment: Wait.. Don't you just want to entirely disable control over the <select>? Then just make it disabled in html: <select disabled>..</select>. Users wont be able to do anything with it (click or whatever)

Comment: Select box must be enabled, we can select the options only through mouse only

Comment: ok, I was confused cause you say something about clicks.. In my example, arrow keys indeed remain enabled, but only after opening the select. But actually, I am not sure you could find a better solution. Maybe others will have a solution, but it seems unlikely to me...